# Eclipse RSE Error: Operation failed. File system input or output error

Tags: java, eclipse, virtualbox

I am trying to connect Eclipse to a Virtualbox instance running Ubuntu on Windows 10, using the Remote Systems Explorer. I am able to establish an SSH-only connection by inputting my username and password, and I can access the file system. However, when I try to actually open a file, I get an RSEF1002 error:

```
Operation failed. File system input or output error
```

I have set chmod 777 on the directory which I would like to work from. I also tried disconnecting and reconnecting my Eclipse connection, and restarting Eclipse. Nothing has worked so far. Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Let me know if there are more details I can provide that might help debug the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. I went and did

```
ls -la
```

in my workspace "***/home/myuser/workspace-cdt***" and and then went into a directory called ***RemoteSystemsTempFiles***
the i saw a directory `"10.160.16.3"` corresponding to the IP of the machine i was working on, but what was important there the owner was root

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mai 16 23:06 10.160.16.3
```

then did

```
chown -R myuser:myuser 10.160.16.3
```

and that's how i sloved my problem. I think that happened because i did and upgrade of eclipse cdt from root and that messed up the directory permission in my workspace.